# Update server-side rendered props dynamically

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-query

I've got posts with comments and like to implement a post view that includes all comments to that post.

My `getServerSideProps` passes the `post` (including all comments) to my page. Whenever a new comment is written the comments should be dynamically updated, but I'm currently facing some problems with that.

My post view:

```
const PostView: NextPage = ({ post }) => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      {post.title}
      <CommentList initialComments={post.comments} postId={post.id} />
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default PostView;

export const getServerSideProps = () => {
  const post = await getPost(); // returns the post and all its comments
  return { props: { post } };
};
```

The `CommentList` component:

```
const CommentList = (initialComments, postId) => {
  const { data: comments } = useQuery(["comments", postId], async () => getComments(), { initialData: initialComments);

  return (
    <>
      Comments: {comments.length}
      ... new comment form ...
      ... list of comments ...
    </>
  );
}
```

The reason why I still want to query comments with `react-query` is simple: comments should be server-side rendered so that they become seo-relevant, while I want human users to get a dynamic list that can be updated.

When writing new comments I update the `QueryClient` of react-query by hand:

```
export const useCreateCommentMutation = (postId: string) => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();

  return useMutation(
    ["comments", postId],
    async (values) =>
      await axios.post("/api/comments", values),
    {
      onSuccess: async res => {
        queryClient.setQueryData<CommentWithAuthor[]>(
          ["comments", postId],
          prev => [...(prev || []), res.data],
        );
      },
    },
  );
};
```

This seems to work at first glance; when I check the DOM the comments are included and when writing new comments they dynamically appear.

Unfortunately, when I refresh the page I get the following error:

> Text content did not match. Server: "3" Client: "4"

3 (or 4) in this case is the `comments.length` output.

What am I doing wrong in this case?

Thanks

Edit 1:

I've also tried fixing it by using `useEffect`:

```
const [usedComments, setUsedComments] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setUsedComments(comments || initialComments);
  }, [comments])
```

And render `usedComments` instead - but unfortunately now the comments are no longer part of the DOM.

Comment: The code generally looks fine. Not sure how a page refresh can cause the mismatch, because the query cache on the client is thrown away at that point. So the server renders the new comments and it should just work like the initial page load. Can you reproduce that behaviour in codesandbox?

Comment: Unfortunately no, can't get codesandbox to work. Any other platform where I could try?

Comment: this might be caused by how `initialData` approach works, according to the documentation: **There is no way to know at what time the query was fetched on the server, so dataUpdatedAt and determining if the query needs refetching is based on when the page loaded instead.** Did you try the [Hydration](https://react-query-v3.tanstack.com/guides/ssr#using-hydration) approach?

Comment: Didn't know about this the Hydration approach - this fixed the error, thanks. (I have no idea how to "accept as answer" works on comments here) @mocherfaoui

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using useState() hook to store that the Comment data . Every time useQuery runs it will update the state which will cause re-rendering of the comment and also.
I can't think of anything other then this. I don't know what your comment json/data look like to do the server side dynamic rendering.

And useQuery runs on user action like click on add new comment button or a time loop.

and your error seems like It is caused by some Server and client attribute of  component.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).